# Difference between column sum in file 1 and column sum in file 2

Tags: linux, unix

I have this input

```
file 1        file 2
A 10             222      77.11    11
B 20             2222     1.215    22
C 30            22222     12.021   33
D 40            222222   145.00    44
```

The output I need is `(11+22+33+44)- (10+20+30+40)  = 110-100=10`
  thank you  in advance for  your help

Comment: i tried this cod but it only for one  file   awk '{x+=$2  } END  {print x}' file 1   i need  cod for 2 file in same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{s1+=$5; s2+=$2} END {print s1-s2}'
```

Or better yet (clever of @falsetru's answer to do the summing with a single variable):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{sum+=$5-$2} END {print sum}'
```

If you want to work with column **N** in file1 and column **M** in file2, this might be "easier", but less efficient:

```
paste <(awk '{print $N}' file1) <(awk '{print $M}' file2.txt) | awk '{sum+=$2-$1} END {print sum}'
```

It's easier in the sense that you don't have to count the right position of the column in the second file, but less efficient because of the added extra `awk` sub-processes.

Comment: what if where the same field like                   file 1 field 1 and file 2 field 1

Comment: –  janos    its wonderfull solutoin its work  very well god plus you  for help me here

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat test.txt
file 1        file 2
A 10             222      77.11    11
B 20             2222     1.215    22
C 30            22222     12.021   33
D 40            222222   145.00    44 
$ tail -n +2 test.txt | awk '{s += $5 - $2} END {print s}'
10
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize `s`.

Comment: Clever of you to sum using a single variable, I improved my answer after seeing yours

Comment: what if where the same field like                   file 1 field 1 and file 2 field 1

Comment: @user2982005, I don't understand what you mean. Could you update your question with example?